# goto statement usage in C++

Tags: c++, goto

I have a `funcA` which I call every msec. by another `funcB`. I want to use goto statement. But when I look at the flow (when `m_tempdata` is not `NULL`), after printing `"stage 2"`, it is also printing `"cleanup starts"`. Normally, I expect to return after printing `"stage 2"` for the next turn. Am I wrong?

```
void ClassA::funcA()
{
    m_tempdata = m_freedata;

    printf("stage 1 \n");

    if (NULL == m_tempdata)
    {
        printf("going cleaning \n" );
        goto cleanup;
    }
    m_freedata = m_tempdata->next;

    printf("stage 2 \n");

cleanup: printf("cleanup starts \n");
    // ... some additional work todo
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to return? `cleanup:` is just a label between your statements. Also, there's no good reason to justify `goto` here :v

Comment: You reap what you sow

Comment: This should be fun...

Answer (score 3):

> Normally, I expect to return after printing "stage 2" for the next
>   turn. Am I wrong?

Yes, **you're wrong**.

In the case where the label wasn't jumped to, the code will simply fall through to it and continue.  A label isn't an *instruction*.  It doesn't cause the program to magically return or jump somewhere else.

Here is a much better way to write this:

```
void ClassA::funcA()
{
  m_tempdata = m_freedata;

  printf("stage 1 \n");

  if (NULL == m_tempdata)
  {
    printf("going cleaning \n" );
    Cleanup();
    return;
  }

  m_freedata = m_tempdata->next;
}

void ClassA::Cleanup()
{
  printf("cleanup starts \n");
  //      ... some additional work todo
}
```

Please don't use `goto`.  It make the code much more difficult to understand, debug and maintain.  Plus you end up making silly mistakes like you did here because you made poor design decisions earlier.  Use modern flow-control constructs instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a good/compelling reason to use `goto` in this code, so don't. Use more readable control flow structures.

```
printf("stage 1\n");
if (NULL != m_tempdata)
{
    printf("stage 2\n");
    // ...
}
else
{
    printf("cleanup starts\n");
    // ...
}
```

If you need to do the cleanup regardless of whether "stage 2" runs or not, remove the `else` block and have the cleanup code at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it stop? There's nothing to interrupt control flow between the statement `printf("stage 2 \n");` and the statement `printf("cleanup starts \n");` (which happens to be labelled `cleanup:`).

If you really want it to interrupt, you'll have to insert a `return` statement before the `cleanup:` label.

But please, seriously reconsider using `goto`. It makes programs very difficult to reason about - always prefer structured flow (`if`s, loops, function calls).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to tell the compiler that the function should exit after "stage 2". If you want it to return you have to actually tell the compiler that by adding a `return` statement.

Comment: Actually, since cleanup is called by goto statement, I was thinking it is only executed when goto is called. Is it possible to let it work without return?

Comment: @AvbAvb You can still use `return` with no expression: `return;`. It will return from the function (with or without a return value) at the point of the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to use a vintage C programming pattern like this one:

```
void do_hot_stuff (void)
{
    void * data1 = malloc (123);
    if (data1 == NULL) goto fail1;

    void * data2 = malloc (123);
    if (data2 == NULL) goto fail2;

    void * data3 = malloc (123);
    if (data3 == NULL) goto fail3;

    // do your hot stuff here

    free (data3);
    fail3:
    free(data2);
    fail2:
    free(data1);
    fail1:
}
```

Frankly I did not use this since I last wrote code for my Amiga back in the late 80's.
Just don't.

Comment: I think you mixed up the labels and the statements at the end :) You can probably still find this kind of stuff in libraries, such as OpenSSL, but I sure hope that people don't continue to write such code. A few years ago, I saw some production code where most functions contained a giant while loop which wrapped the "hot stuff" in order to catch exceptional cases. Nasty stuff, but still better than `goto` :)

Comment: @MihaiTodor Mmmm... I think the statement placement is OK (if you fail to allocate data3, you just have to free data2 & data1), but anyway this stuff is good for museums.

Comment: Ah, right :)) Another good example to never use such things :)